# How to use tkinter to create two buttons and when user clicks the correct one, it will run another window

Tags: python, tkinter, game-development

I am designing a game project for our mastermind class and I decided to use python tkinter, I want to have a feature that two buttons will appear and when user pushes the correct one, it will open up another window and show the other three options (multiple choice).
I've created two buttons but they don't combine into the text windows. I know I need a way to insert two buttons inside one window, but what's the way of adding?

```
root = Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=30, undo=True, autoseparators=False)
text.pack()
text.insert(tk.INSERT, 'This will test your chemistry ability. Enter y or n to start')
```

This above codes are the intro page which will ask user to input y or n. So do I need to continue by `tk.Button` or other ways?

Comment: grammar of adding text is like 
text["text"] = "This will test your chemistry ability. Enter y or n to start"

Comment: to add a widget to window use `.pack()`, `.grid()` or `.place()` (not suggested)

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus incorrect, Text widget doesn't have attribute `text`, OP inserts text the correct way tho I am a bit confused of what exactly is the question

Comment: You can put the two buttons like how you put the text box.

Comment: I suggest You make it a label (not text as in the post) and user can choose by pressing a button

Comment: Well, for one button give `command` and for the fake one, dont give `command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, MCQ):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Magic Button 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MCQ))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Magic Button 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.destroy())
        button2.pack()


class MCQ(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="MCQ test!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Option1",
                            command=lambda: self.correspondingBehavior('Option1'))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Option2",
                            command=lambda: self.correspondingBehavior('Option2'))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Option3",
                            command=lambda: self.correspondingBehavior('Option3'))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit",
                            command=lambda: controller.destroy())
        button4.pack()

    def correspondingBehavior(self,choice):
        print(choice)
    


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Something went wrong...
When I run the program to test, something like ```AttributeError: 'MCQ' object has no attribute 'correspondingBehavior'``` error occurred, and I didn't change a lot of content. Thank you a lot for your codes!

Comment: @SusieXue, i guess you delete the `correspondingBehavior` function.

Comment: @SusieXue,so what did you change?

Comment: Its all of a sudden... I changed the text inside to my own ones and the first time it executes, and the second time it refused to execute anymore...

Comment: I changed the text in ```tk.button```, and I changed the text in ```correspondingBehavior``` too. I used pycharm and it worked for the first time.

Comment: Also, I didn't delete the ```correspondingBehavior``` function, but the ```self``` is grey and pycharm says ```Parameter 'self' value is not used```

Comment: Update: I checked the codes once more and found that I forgot an indent for the ```correspondingBehavior``` function, thanks to those masters who help me!

Comment: @SusieXue, glad it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something You want:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button


root = Tk()

Label(root, text='This will test your chemistry ability.').pack(padx=10, pady=10)

Button(root, text='Continue').pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
Button(root, text='Cancel', command=root.quit).pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button


root = Tk()

Label(root, text='This will test your chemistry ability.').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    def newWindow():
        root.destroy()
        root1 = Tk()
        """ YOUR CODE FOR OTHER WINDOW"""
        root1.mianloop()
Button(root, text='Continue',command=newWindow).pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
Button(root, text='Cancel', command=root.quit).pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
```